# CSS not displaying in HTML file on local server

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple HTML file that i'm running on a local server, as it's soon to be turned into a php file. When I run it from the server however, the CSS doesn't display on the page. Opening the index.html file in a web browser shows it just fine.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Content goes here"/>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="http://Link.com"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="mailto:support@link.com">
                        <img src="images/email.png"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://Twitter.com/link">
                        <img src="images/twitter.png"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
.header {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: 61px;
}

    .logo {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .navigation {
        float: right;
    }

        .navigation li {
            width:60px;
            height:60px;
            float:left;
            margin-left:14px;
            border-radius:30px;
        }

        .navigation li a {
            width:60px;
            height:60px;
            float:left;
            background-color:#576f85;
            border-radius:30px;
        }

        .navigation li a img {
            padding-left:14px;
            padding-top:14px;
            padding-right:14px;
            padding-bottom:14px;
        }
```

Comment: Did you include the CSS file?

Comment: What is your directory file structure? Is the `CSS` file in the same folder as the `HTML` file or in some other like `css/style.css` ?

Comment: check the console. your `css` path is wrong perhaps. __AND what this question has anything to do with php?__

Comment: The file is in the same folder. It works with the CSS file when index.html is opened in a browser.

Comment: Check for the case? `style.css` and `Style.css` are different on the server...

Comment: @NikhilPatel Same case.

Comment: The solution seemed to be that i was accessing it through localhost and not localhost:8234. Accessing it that way works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press ctrl + shift + del, and remove all cache from your browser :) I have to that once in a while to get css working wi

Answer (score 0):

Include the css file like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Comment: I stripped out everything unnecessary, and accidentally took that line. It's back now, but still doesn't work.

Comment: have you uploaded css file over server?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you had included the CSS within the HTML originally, viewed it within your browser (locally) then moved it to a separate .css file and forgotten to include the link as per hitchdiddy's answer above.

Now when you view it on your local server it can't find the CSS but the older page has been cached by your browser for the local page which is why you still see your styling when viewing it directly.

Comment: Nope. Tried it in firefox (not opened that in weeks). It works in firefox.